# css image doesn't fill div

Tags: html, css, image

I have a DIV that is 100% width..... inside a grid system .. the total grid is 1140px..

anyway inside the div that is 100% i inserted a image...

problem is if the div background is black... there is like 1cm at the bottom that still shows the black color.

like this

http://jsfiddle.net/hb3QK/3/

```
<div style="background:black; width:100%;">
  <img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/ofq9tg.png" >
```

should i be using a float on the image? or using a display:block?

Comment: The 1cm gap is because `<img>` is `display: inline` by default. Switching to `display: block` will remove it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here you do
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/hb3QK/4/

```
img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
display:block;
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

add `display: block;` to style of image.

Comment: i just said the required part, setting height auto is not required as its default

Comment: indeed, but your answer definitely came second, and San's answer is more than enough.

Comment: it is not important who's came first or second...as long as it helps someone....cheers people :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can add if you need to keep it inline.
line-height: 0;
to the image style.